# API GET request returns undefined in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, promise, get

I'm new to Node JS and still figuring out how API GET requests are working. I'm trying to call API GET request using Node Js, function is supposed to get data from the servers and url will be "url/books?name=" where "name" will be passed to the function from input field. So far I have this function

```
async function getBooksInfo(name) {
    
    const url = `https://test/books?name=${name}`;

     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        https.get(url, res => {
            res.setEncoding("utf8");
            let body = "";
            res.on("data", data => {
                body += data;
            });
            res.on("end", () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(body)
                                  
            });
             res.on("error", (e) => {
                reject(e);
            });
        });
    })
}
```

and another function will create stream of inputs,

```
async function storeInfo() {
const date = readLine().trim();
const result = await getBooksInfo(date);
const isEmpty = !Object.keys(result).length;
if (isEmpty) {
 ws.write('We don't have this book in our database');
  } else {
      ws.write(`Book Name: ${result.bookName}`);
      ws.write(`Year: ${result.year}\n`)
  }
}
```

but for some reason stream of inputs return undefined, I don't seems to understand what could be the issue. Any help and suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Updated: this is what console.log shows

```
{
  page: 1,
  per_page: 100,
  total_pages: 20,
  data: [
    {
      bookName: 'test',
      year: 1975,
      author: "test,
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maybe the API is returning an array of books, not just a single book?

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` show?

Comment: @Barmar updated my post with console.log data

Comment: `result.data[0].bookName`

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your suggestion, but we can't change that part of the coding, we're displaying it like ${result.bookName}` in a whole application and using ${result.year} in other functions, is there a way to pass data correctly from getBooksInfo function?

Comment: But that's not where the value is in the JSON.

Comment: If you can't change how you print it, you have to change what the controller returns, or call a different controller function.

Comment: Can you change `getBooksInfo`? Use `resolve(body.data[0])`

Comment: @Barmar thank you, that seems to work but in case if (body.data[0]} returns empty array or undefined, code breaks.

Comment: Obviously you need to check whether there's anything there before trying to use it.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I'm checking it in getBooksInfo  
  function res.on("end", () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body); if(body.data[0] != undefined  {resolve(body.data[0] }
            });  still breaks

Comment: You need an `else` that resolves with a different, default value.